# How to update to max value of field +1?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to update field **myField** in a record in table **myTable** to the max value of that same field +1.

I've tried the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myField = max(myField)+1
WHERE myField = 121 and foriegnKey = 124
```

However I got the following Error:

**The query does not include the specified expression 'myField' as part of an aggregate function**

I've found an answer to this problem in MySQL, but it doesn't work for me:

```
UPDATE myTable set field = 
((SELECT maxField 
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(myField) AS maxField  
FROM myTable) AS q) + 1) 
WHERE myField = 121 and foriegnKey = 124
```

I got the following error:

**Operation must use an updateable query**

Comment: There's almost no good reason for ever needing to do this

Comment: @Strawberry, I know. I'm fixing a corrupt database, so I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are aware that MAX()+1 techniques are usually a Bad Idea™, in your specific case you should be able to use the DMax() domain aggregate function. I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems that you want something like this:

```sql
UPDATE myTable SET myField = DMax("myField", "myTable") + 1
WHERE myField = 121 and foriegnKey = 124
```